# Which running/biking apps (Strava, Runtastic, Endomondo, ...) use barometer for proper elevation gain?

Tags: applications, iphone, apple-watch

After having read this blog [(More GPS Cycling Tests: Things are Pretty Bad and There’s Little Hope)](http://regex.info/blog/2015-05-15/2571) about the inaccuracies in apps like Strava and Runtastic, I'm curious which similar apps produces reasonably accurate elevation gain/profile.

Here, Runmeter seems a good option. But which others have you found?
I would consider an app reasonably accurate if it produced results close to a Sigma bike computer with altimeter.

Comment: I use the Workout app on my  Watch and it works fine. I don't think it has a barometer.

Answer (score 1):

[iSmoothRun](http://www.ismoothrun.com) records elevation data using the iPhone's barometric altimeter. This app can sync with various storage and tracking services, such as Dropbox, RunKeeper, Strava, etc.

The barometric data is preserved when syncing or exporting GPX/TCX files from iSmoothRun (although I currently have to tweak the header of the GPX file and manually upload to Strava in order for Strava to respect the barometric data recorded by iSmoothRun instead of discarding it in favor of its own measurements based on topographic data).

Comment: Could someone disclose how the header should be tweaked to trick Strava into respecting my barometric data?

Comment: In GPX files, edit the root `gpx` element so that it has a `creator` attribute that includes the substring "with barometer". The creator attribute may already be there, in which case you can just append the text "with barometer" to its value, or you can add the creator attribute to the gpx element. Here is what it should look like: `<gpx creator="iSmoothRun - with barometer" ....> data goes here </gpx>`.